# How can I change the default Excel XML refresh timeout (using VBA)?

Tags: xml, vba, timeout

I've found a bit of VBA code that refreshes the data in an XML map:

```
ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("Map").DataBinding.Refresh
```

The server providing the xml source gets busy sometimes, so I'd like to be able to override the default timeout to something very short, e.g. 5 seconds, and skip to the next section of code when this happens. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can cancel while the map is binding (so if it is successful but still takes 5 seconds there is no way to cancel it). You can react to a timeout failure (handle the `BindingError` event).

It is sloppy but you could make the binding be asynchronous (`ASync` property) and put a 5 second wait before continuing on (or use the `BindingInProgress` property in conjunction). Then your code after the refresh gets executed no matter what (timeout or not).